# How to avoid iconv error to halt my program

Tags: linux, bash, shell, character-encoding, iconv

I have a utf-8 document to be convert to big5 encoding using `iconv` with the code below

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t big5 $inputFile -o $outputFile
```

However there are some utf-8 characters encoding is not complete because I set byte size limit in each line in the document like 40 bytes in a line so some utf-8 characters will be cut.

Since the incomplete encoding of utf-8 characters leads to the error that `iconv` cannot find the corresponding big5 encode for the incomplete utf-8 characters encoding and the iconv stops.

Is there any why to avoid the iconv to halt and skip the incomplete utf-8 characters encoding and continue convert the following document to big5 encoding document?

Comment: Why not just allow longer lines?

Comment: This is the fixed spec. I cannot change the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that is what you are looking for, but, to quote `man iconv`:

> DESCRIPTION
>          The iconv program converts the encoding of characters in inputfile, or
>          from the standard input if no filename is specified, from one coded
>          character set to another.
>
> OPTIONS
>
> > **-c     Omit invalid characters from output.**
> >       
> >       [...]

The *man* is not really clear, but when you use that option, characters in the source file invalid given the source encoding are discarded.